# eglInitialize: No available renderers

Tags: electron

I am trying to use Electron. I am following their guide : https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-first-app

but when I run `npm run start` I get this error :

```
Hello from Electron ­ƒæï
[1816:0521/233607.695:ERROR:gl_display.cc(508)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eg
lInitialize: No available renderers.
[1816:0521/233607.695:ERROR:gl_display.cc(920)] eglInitialize D3D11 failed with
error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[1816:0521/233607.805:ERROR:gl_display.cc(508)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglCr
eateContext: Requested GLES version (3.0) is greater than max supported (2, 0).
[1816:0521/233607.805:ERROR:gl_context_egl.cc(370)] eglCreateContext failed with
 error EGL_SUCCESS
[1816:0521/233607.815:ERROR:gl_display.cc(508)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglCr
eateContext: Requested GLES version (3.0) is greater than max supported (2, 0).
[1816:0521/233607.815:ERROR:gl_context_egl.cc(370)] eglCreateContext failed with
 error EGL_SUCCESS
[1816:0521/233607.815:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(884)] Failed to create GLES3
context, fallback to GLES2.
[5960:0521/233807.613:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(523)] Passthrough is not supported, GL i
s disabled, ANGLE is
```

How can I fix this ?

additional infos :

I use Windows 7, so I used `npm install electron@v22.3.10` because versions >=23 are no more compatible with win7 therefore with `npm install electron --save-dev` I was having the infamous `error code ELIFECYCLE error errno 3221225785`.

Chrome (*Version 106.0.5249.121 (Build officiel) (64 bits)*) runs fine on this computer though and does not complain about my graphic drivers.

My goal with Electron is to turn my html5 game into an arm64 Linux executable.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are seeing suggests that there is an issue with the GPU (Graphics Processing Unit) acceleration in Electron.
Specifically, the error message says that [EGL (Embedded-System Graphics Library)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EGL_(API)), which is a layer between graphics rendering APIs (like OpenGL) and the underlying native platform windowing system, cannot find any available renderers.
It also says that the requested [GLES (OpenGL ES)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES) version is higher than what is supported.

[Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/), like Chrome, defaults to using hardware acceleration when available. This means that it tries to use the computer's GPU to perform some heavy lifting related to rendering. This can cause problems on some systems, especially older ones or ones with less common graphics hardware or drivers.

First, make sure to **update your graphics drivers** and have the latest drivers installed for your graphics hardware.

If the issue persists, try and **disable hardware acceleration** in your Electron application. This can be done by calling the `app.disableHardwareAcceleration()` function in your main process before you create any browser windows.
[Example from here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/offscreen-rendering#software-output-device):

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

app.disableHardwareAcceleration()

function createWindow () {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
    }
    })

    win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
```

You can also force software rendering, using the Chromium's rendering engine option to use software rendering when hardware acceleration is not available. You can set the `--ignore-gpu-blacklist` command line switches to enable this:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ignore-gpu-blacklist')

function createWindow () {
    // ... same as before ...
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
```

Comment: Thanks, but since it's a game I create I can't disable GPU. I did not want to disable the blacklist neither because it may cause crashes for the players, but I'll try, because they won't be able to play anyway if their GPU is blacklisted like mine.

Comment: @Diego That makes senses. Let me know if you find a solution.